# vCenter Installation stuck at 56%

Tags: virtualbox, vmware, vcenter

I installed vCenter on Virtualbox by importing the `vmdk` files. But afterI start the vCenter VM and go the UI, I see that its stuck at 56% and not progressing at all.

I've ensured that DNS is working on the vCenter VM.

Any idea what the issue is or what to check in order to resolve it.

[image]

Comment: Vecnter is a VM virtualizing APP.  I am skeptical the VBOX could nest another Virtualizing APP inside VBOX.

Comment: @john Vcenter is the management tool for virtualized systems. It's more like the HyperV management UI than the HyperV server.

Comment: Do you know that Vcenter is supported on VirtualBox? Extracting VMDK files indicates to me you're using a hack for getting VMware stuff to work on VBox, but Vcenter is more than just another VMware thing.

Comment: Here is how you might try to proceed:  https://www.virtualizationhowto.com/2021/02/virtualbox-nested-virtualization-with-vmware-esxi/   ... But that is ESXi and not Vcenter.

Comment: It will be vastly easier to pick one software vendor and work with those products. VMware is the best and most flexible of the vendor selection and their stuff generally works together as you as expecting.